# File Search in a Domain network

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to search for a string in a file ,whose location i.e file and folder name in a computer is known to me. File can be present in any computer over the domain. There can be multiple occurrences of the file as well as the keyword.

This is the code I have written:

```
namespace newprog
{
class Program
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] dirs = Directory.Getfiles("C:\ABC");
        Console.WriteLine("Results {0}", dirs.Length);
        try
        {
            foreach (string dir in dirs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dir);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

In the above code I have found files in a local directory i.e. ABC. But now I want search a particular file from all the computers over the whole domain and also need to check the presence of a keyword in those files found.

My domnain name is pqr.rst.com and I want know a file ab.txt. So how do I use the getfiles command.

**What I know**

> 1. I can generate the list of all computers in  the domain in a text file.
> 2. I know how to search for a file in my local directories like I di above.

**My question**

> How do I search occurrences of a file in the whole domain and then how
>   to check for a keyword in them.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post the code you have already written and point out the parts where you are stuck, so we can help you.